# What is the backend of matplotlib for inline plotting in jupyter

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter

I want to implement a custom backend of matplotlib, so I want to read the code of backend of matplotlib for inline plotting in jupyter for reference. Can anyone point me the source code of that ? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the used backend by:

```
%pylab inline
matplotlib.get_backend()

>> 'module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline'
```

Looking at the sourcecode in that module shows that the backend is imported from `matplotlib.backends.backend_agg`

The help for [matplotlibrc file](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html#a-sample-matplotlibrc-file) also has some information for specifying a new backend.

```
# The default backend; one of GTK GTKAgg GTKCairo GTK3Agg GTK3Cairo
# MacOSX Qt4Agg Qt5Agg TkAgg WX WXAgg Agg Cairo GDK PS PDF SVG
# Template.
# You can also deploy your own backend outside of matplotlib by
# referring to the module name (which must be in the PYTHONPATH) as
# 'module://my_backend'.
backend      : qt5agg
```